# How to handle JSON Objects in Javascript Functions since Karate 1.3.0?

Tags: javascript, object, karate

Until Karate version 1.2.0 inclusive, I could do the following in Feature Files:

```
    * def checkObj =
    """
        function(obj) {
            const keys = Object.keys(obj);
            print("### object:", JSON.stringify(obj));
            print("### keys:", keys);
            keys.forEach(key => {
                print("### key:", key);
                print("### value:", myObj[key]);
            });
        }
    """ 
    * def myObj = { foo: "bar" }
    * checkObj(myObj)
```

... and I received as expected:

```
### object: {"foo":"bar"}
### keys: foo
### key: foo
### value: bar
```

But since Karate 1.3.0 the same code gives me instead:

```
### object: {}
### keys: get,values,clear,replaceAll,entrySet,forEach,containsValue,keySet,getOrDefault,remove,put,clone,isEmpty,replace,size,merge,putAll,putIfAbsent,compute,containsKey,computeIfAbsent,computeIfPresent,equals,toString,hashCode
### key: get
### value: undefined
### key: values
### value: undefined
### key: clear
### value: undefined
### key: replaceAll
### value: undefined
### key: entrySet
### value: undefined
### key: forEach
### value: undefined
### key: containsValue
### value: undefined
### key: keySet
### value: undefined
### key: getOrDefault
### value: undefined
### key: remove
### value: undefined
### key: put
### value: undefined
### key: clone
### value: undefined
### key: isEmpty
### value: undefined
### key: replace
### value: undefined
### key: size
### value: undefined
### key: merge
### value: undefined
### key: putAll
### value: undefined
### key: putIfAbsent
### value: undefined
### key: compute
### value: undefined
### key: containsKey
### value: undefined
### key: computeIfAbsent
### value: undefined
### key: computeIfPresent
### value: undefined
### key: equals
### value: undefined
### key: toString
### value: function toString() { [native code] }
### key: hashCode
### value: undefined
```

In contrast, with inline Javascript things still work as expected, interestingly:

```
    * def myObj = { foo: "bar" }
    * print("### object:", JSON.stringify(myObj))
    * print("### key(s):", Object.keys(myObj))
    * print("### value:", myObj.foo)
```

Output:

```
### object: {"foo":"bar"}
### key(s): foo
### value: bar
```

I suspect this is a bug or at least an undocumented breaking change, at least I didn't find anything about it in the release notes. Or is there another way (or even a workaround) to process JSON objects in the new Karate versions that I overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2224

Please use 1.4.0.RC3 and let us know how it goes. Note that this requires [Java 11+](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2083), but you should be doing that migration anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that my code works again with version 1.4.0.RC3. Is there already a schedule when we can expect approximately the final version 1.4.0?

Comment: @DrundaNibel I would say that you can start using that RC3 and we may have one more RC before final. most likely within a month. a few users are already using RC3 without issues and I consider it "stable"

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm now getting a JS error with 1.4.0.RC3 on some other regression tests that ran fine up to 1.2.0 (and even don't seem to have any problems with 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 either). For more details I will research further and open another issue if necessary ... By the way: We have been using Java 11 for a while anyway.

Comment: @DrundaNibel yes please open an issue and a way to replicate. we had a high confidence that 1.4.0.RC3 had all the JS sorted out ... until now :(

Comment: I have just reported an issue on my findings: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2264